# Rewriting OpenCV C++ to EmguCV C# - how to work with pointers?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to convert C++ code written OpenCV 2.x to Emgu.CV in C#.

I have a function in C++:

```
cv::Mat computeMatXGradient(const cv::Mat &mat) {
    cv::Mat out(mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_64F);
    for (int y = 0; y < mat.rows; ++y) {
        const uchar* Mr = mat.ptr<uchar>(y);
        double* Or = out.ptr<double>(y);
        Or[0] = Mr[1] - Mr[0];
        for (int x = 1; x < mat.cols - 1; ++x) {
            Or[x] = (Mr[x + 1] - Mr[x - 1]) / 2.0;
        }
        Or[mat.cols - 1] = Mr[mat.cols - 1] - Mr[mat.cols - 2];
    }
    return out;
}
```

How to do the same thing in C# with EmguCV efficiently?

So far - I have this C# code:
(I can't test it because a lot of code is missing)

```
Mat computeMatXGradient(Mat inMat)
{
    Mat outMat = new Mat(inMat.Rows, inMat.Cols, DepthType.Cv64F, inMat.NumberOfChannels);
    for (int y = 0; y < inMat.Rows; ++y)
    {
        // unsafe is required if I'm using pointers
        unsafe {
            byte* Mr = (byte*) inMat.DataPointer;
            double* Or = (double*) outMat.DataPointer;
            Or[0] = Mr[1] - Mr[0];
            for (int x = 1; x < inMat.Cols - 1; ++x)
            {
               Or[x] = (Mr[x + 1] - Mr[x - 1]) / 2.0;
            }
            Or[inMat.Cols - 1] = Mr[inMat.Cols - 1] - Mr[inMat.Cols - 2];
        }
    }
    return outMat;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is my C# code correct?
2. Is there better/more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting `inMat` to an array `inM`, then calculating the values you need in another array `Or`, and finally converting the latter array to the output `Mat` `outMat`.

**Note:** I considered `NumberOfChannels` to be 1 as I think this will be always the case.

```
Mat computeMatXGradient(Mat inMat)
{
    int x, y;
    byte[] inM, Mr;
    double[] Or;
    inM = new byte[(int)inMat.Total];
    inMat.CopyTo(inM);
    Mr = new byte[inMat.Cols];
    Or = new double[inMat.Rows * inMat.Cols];
    for (y = 0; y < inMat.Rows; y++)
    {
        Array.Copy(inM, y * inMat.Cols, Mr, 0, inMat.Cols);
        Or[y * inMat.Cols] = Mr[1] - Mr[0];
        for (x = 1; x < inMat.Cols - 1; x++)
           Or[y * inMat.Cols + x] = (Mr[x + 1] - Mr[x - 1]) / 2.0;
        Or[y * inMat.Cols + inMat.Cols - 1] = Mr[inMat.Cols - 1] - Mr[inMat.Cols - 2];
    }
    Mat outMat = new Mat(inMat.Rows, inMat.Cols, DepthType.Cv64F, 1);
    Marshal.Copy(Or, 0, outMat.DataPointer, inMat.Rows * inMat.Cols);
    return outMat;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is save code to do equivalent.  Did not test.  I checked the OpenCV library to get the structure of Mat.  The real structure in OpenCV has a pointer to the data.  Instead I made an array of bytes.  So if you were loading/writing a OpenCV struct you would need an interface to convert.  The output matrix is eight times the input since input is an array of bytes and output is an array double.

The code would be better if there was an input byte[][] and an output double[][].

```
public class Mat
{
    public int flags;
    //! the array dimensionality, >= 2
    public int dims;
    //! the number of rows and columns or (-1, -1) when the array has more than 2 dimensions
    public int rows;
    public int cols;
    //! pointer to the data
    public byte[] data;
    //! pointer to the reference counter;
    // when array points to user-allocated data, the pointer is NULL
    public Mat[] refcount;
    // other members
    public Mat computeMatXGradient(Mat inMat)
    {
        Mat outMat = new Mat();
        outMat.rows = inMat.rows;
        outMat.cols = inMat.cols;
        outMat.flags = inMat.flags;  //include depthType and NumberofChannels
        outMat.dims = inMat.dims;
        outMat.data = new byte[inMat.rows * inMat.cols * sizeof(Double)];
        int outIndex = 0;
        byte[] d = new byte[sizeof(double)];
        for (int y = 0; y < inMat.rows; ++y)
        {
            int inRowIndex = y * inMat.cols;
            d = BitConverter.GetBytes((double)(inMat.data[inRowIndex + 1] - inMat.data[inRowIndex]));
            Array.Copy(d, 0, outMat.data, outIndex, sizeof(double));
            outIndex += sizeof(double);
            for (int x = 1; x < inMat.cols - 1; ++x)
            {
                d = BitConverter.GetBytes((double)(inMat.data[inRowIndex + x + 1] - inMat.data[inRowIndex + x - 1]) / 2.0);
                Array.Copy(d, 0, outMat.data, outIndex,sizeof(double));
                outIndex += sizeof(double);
            }
            d = BitConverter.GetBytes((double)(inMat.data[inRowIndex + inMat.cols - 1] - inMat.data[inRowIndex - inMat.cols - 2]));
            Array.Copy(d, 0, outMat.data, outIndex, sizeof(double));
        }
        return outMat;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for few reasons. You can't assign outMat.data, because it is readonly.

Comment: What are your requirements?  To have same interface and functionality of original code; or to have just same functionality?  OpenCV has a generic Matrix structure.  Do you need the generic structure if you are implementing in c#?  I made two changes to original code that can be modified 1) Made a class instead of structure 2) Changed to pointer to the data to an array to avoid a memory leak.  I can change data to a IntPtr and then allocate memory for the data to make same as CV.  But allocating memory can cause a memory leak.

Comment: My teachers and co-workers always say code should have margins to make it easy to read and to add notes when debugging.  Removing the space definitely does not make it look nicer.  Just harder to read.

Comment: There is no need to define own Mat type as EmguCV (c# opencv wrapper) already provides this type. This solution won't be compatible. Plz check tags.